# Sending Response outside akka Actor System

Tags: scala, akka, akka-actor

I have a play(2.4.2 which has akka 2.4.18) application in which I am using akka actors for uploading a file. I have a parent supervisor Actor with this kind of hierarchy

> UploadSupervisor ---child---> UploadActor ---child--->
>   DataWriteActor &  MetaWriteActor

The leaf actors MetaWriteActor  & DataWriteActor does the actual writing. A very simplified version of my code is below:

First I have a actor supervisor:

```
class UploadSupervisor extends Actor {
  val uploadActor = context.actorOf(Props(new UploadActor), "UploadActor") 
 override def supervisorStrategy = OneForOneStrategy() {
    case _: Throwable => Restart
 }

override def receive: Receive = {
  case data: Data => uploadActor ! data
  case meta: MetaInfo => uploadActor ! meta
  //How do I send response outside of actor system?
  case dataSuccess: DataUploadResponse => ??? //Line 10
  case metaSuccess: MetaUploadResponse => ??? //Line 11

}

object UploadSupervisor {
  val uploadSupervisor = Akka.system
    .actorOf(Props(new UploadSupervisor), "UploadSupervisor")
}
//Request & Response case classes
case class Data(content: String)
case class MetaInfo(id: String, createdDate: Timestamp)

case class DataUploadResponse(location: String)
case class MetaUploadResponse(location: String)
```

UploadActor:-

```
class UploadActor extends Actor {  
val dataWriteActor = context.actorOf(Props(new DataWriteActor), "dataWriteActor")  
val metaWriteActor = context.actorOf(Props(new MetaWriteActor), "UploadActor")

override def receive = {   
case data: Data => dataWriteActor ! data   
case meta: MetaInfo => metaWriteActor ! meta   
case dataResp: DataUploadResponse => context.parent ! dataResp   
case metaResp: MetaUploadResponse => context.parent ! metaResp 

 }
}
```

DataWriteActor :

```
class DataWriteActor extends Actor {
  case data: Data => //Do the writing 
                     println("data write completed")
                     sender() ! DataUploadResponse("someLocation")  

}
```

MetaWriteActor

```
class MetaWriteActor extends Actor {
  case meta: MetaInfo=> //Do the writing 
                     println(" meta info writing completed")
                     sender() ! MetaUploadResponse("someOtherLocation")  

}
```

Somewhere outside Actor system:-

```
implicit val timeout = Timeout(10 seconds)
val f1 = UploadSupervisor.uploadSupervisor ? Data("Hello Akka").mapTo(implicitly[scala.reflect.ClassTag[DataUploadResponse]])

val f2 = UploadSupervisor.uploadSupervisor ? MetaInfo("1234", new Timestamp(new Date().getTime).mapTo(implicitly[scala.reflect.ClassTag[MetaUploadResponse]])

//Do something with futures
```

The question is how to send the response outside the actor system? Because in Line 10 & 11, I can't use sender ! msg because the current sender is the UploadActor.

Comment: "The question is how to send the response outside the actor system?" what do you mean with outside system? One way would be to use a messaging middle ware  and send the message there from your actor. The consumer subscribes to it and consumes from there. Akka also uses similar concept but as long as I know it is limited to actors only.

Comment: @Imran I mean from UploadSupervisor(Line 10 & 11)  to the Main thread where I am using "?" (ask) to get the values

Comment: @Imran Can you please suggest one such messaging middle-ware which I can explore? Also, Assuming that I am not planning to instantiate multiple instance of these actors. How do you feel about making UploadActor  singleton (class to object). Then I can  call `UploadActor.dataWriteActor ? Data("Hello Akka")` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could keep in `UploadSupervisor` references to the initial senders:

```
class UploadSupervisor extends Actor {
  val uploadActor = context.actorOf(Props[UploadActor], "UploadActor")

  override val supervisorStrategy = OneForOneStrategy() {
    case _ => Restart
  }

  var dataSender: Option[ActorRef] = None
  var metaSender: Option[ActorRef] = None

  def receive = {
    case data: Data =>
      val s = sender
      dataSender = Option(s)
      uploadActor ! data
    case meta: MetaInfo =>
      val s = sender
      metaSender = Option(s)
      uploadActor ! meta
    case dataSuccess: DataUploadResponse =>
      dataSender.foreach(_ ! dataSuccess)
    case metaSuccess: MetaUploadResponse =>
      metaSender.foreach(_ ! metaSuccess)
  }
}
```

To send messages to `UploadSupervisor`:

```
implicit val timeout = Timeout(10 seconds)

val f1 = (UploadSupervisor.uploadSupervisor ? Data("Hello Akka")).mapTo[DataUploadResponse]

val f2 = (UploadSupervisor.uploadSupervisor ? MetaInfo("1234", new Timestamp(new Date().getTime)).mapTo[MetaUploadResponse]
```

---

The above assumes that you're sending one `Data` message and one `MetaInfo` message to `UploadSupervisor` at a time. This approach will break down if you send multiple `Data` and `MetaInfo` messages and expect concurrent replies. A more general solution is to include the reference to the initial sender in additional case classes that wrap your existing case classes, passing this reference through your actor hierarchy:

```
case class DataMsg(data: Data, target: ActorRef)
case class MetaInfoMsg(metaInfo: MetaInfo, target: ActorRef)

case class DataUploadMsg(response: DataUploadResponse, target: ActorRef)
case class MetaUploadMsg(response: MetaUploadResponse, target: ActorRef)

class UploadSupervisor extends Actor {
  val uploadActor = context.actorOf(Props[UploadActor], "UploadActor")

  override val supervisorStrategy = OneForOneStrategy() {
    case _ => Restart
  }

  def receive = {
    case data: Data =>
      val s = sender
      uploadActor ! DataMsg(data, s)
    case meta: MetaInfo =>
      val s = sender
      uploadActor ! MetaInfoMsg(meta, s)
    case DataUploadMsg(response, target) =>
      target ! response
    case MetaUploadMsg(response, target) =>
      target ! response
  }
}
```

The `UploadActor`:

```
class UploadActor extends Actor {  
  val dataWriteActor = context.actorOf(Props[DataWriteActor], "dataWriteActor")  
  val metaWriteActor = context.actorOf(Props[MetaWriteActor], "UploadActor")

  def receive = {   
    case data: DataMsg => dataWriteActor ! data   
    case meta: MetaInfoMsg => metaWriteActor ! meta   
    case dataResp: DataUploadMsg => context.parent ! dataResp   
    case metaResp: MetaUploadMsg => context.parent ! metaResp 
  }
}
```

The writers:

```
class DataWriteActor extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case DataMsg(data, target) =>
      // do the writing 
      println("data write completed")
      sender ! DataUploadMsg(DataUploadResponse("someLocation"), target)
  }
}

class MetaWriteActor extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case MetaInfoMsg(meta, target) =>
      // do the writing 
      println("meta info writing completed")
      sender ! MetaUploadMsg(MetaUploadResponse("someOtherLocation"), target) 
  }
}
```

Comment: Liked the 2nd approach better. Though it makes me create couple of extra case classes but, wouldn't mind doing it. Thanks for the help. Accepting the answer.